# Partial Sum of series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to figure out the formula for the partial sum of $\displaystyle \sum \frac{2n-1}{2^n}$. Any ideas?

Comment: everything, can't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\text{For}\;\;|x|<1\;,\;\;f(x):=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies f'(x)=\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n\;\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without using derivatives. I hope it is correct.

$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{2n-1}{2^n}=2\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n}{2^n}-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^n}$

I think the only problem now is to calculate the sum with the n in the numerator. The other sum can easily be calculated with the formula for the geometric series.

$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n+1}{2^{n+1}}-\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{n}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n}{2^n}+\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}-\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{2^n}$

Now you have:
$\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{n}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ehj0k4835dd this should be the result

Comment: Well, I checked my solution again, and I think it is correct (or am I wrong?) Just solve the equation...